# Laravel 8 Background photo does't appear

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-8

```
<div class="site-blocks-cover overlay bg-light" style=" background-image: url('public/template/images/hero_bg_1.jpg')" id="home-section">
```

The photo doesn't appear on top of website.Also i didn't receive any error
[the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFXKR.png)

Comment: If the HTML with that `div` is in the public directory the path to the image is incorrect. If that is case remove the `public/` from the image URL in the styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `url` function of Laravel

```
background-image:url({{url('template/images/hero_bg_1.jpg')}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must add {{url(' ')}} this to echo Your image
so your code must be

```
<div class="site-blocks-cover overlay bg-light" style=" background-image: url('{{url('public/template/images/hero_bg_1.jpg')}}')" id="home-section">
```

and another one you can use it asset()
like this

```
<div class="site-blocks-cover overlay bg-light" style=" background-image: url('{{asset('public/template/images/hero_bg_1.jpg')}}')" id="home-section">
```